# Elasticsearch query works only after 'sleep'

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have the following test, that does not pass (query returns no results):

```
    # es object init and data population code here
    query = \
    { 
        "query": { 
            "match_phrase":{ 
                "name": {
                    "query": 'element level: 0, index in level: 0'
                }
            } 
        } 
    }
    res = self.es.search(index=self.idxName, body={"query": query})
    self.assertEquals(len(res['hits']['hits']), 1)
```

But when I add a 'sleep' call, it does pass (query returns one result as expected).

```
    # es object init and data population code here
    query = \
    { 
        "query": { 
            "match_phrase":{ 
                "name": {
                    "query": 'element level: 0, index in level: 0'
                }
            } 
        } 
    }
    import time
    time.sleep(1)
    res = self.es.search(index=self.idxName, body={"query": query})
    self.assertEquals(len(res['hits']['hits']), 1)
```

Can anyone explain what is happening please?

Comment: It looks like the problem is in the code that you omitted, above the `query = ...`

Comment: How is that? Why should the code start working when I add a 'sleep' call?

Comment: Because there's probably something initialising above this code. Adding the sleep here, right before the actual call, might allow that "something" to initialise properly. To clarify: you only define a query in the first command I see. That doesn't take any time at all, the query is actually being executed in the `self.es.search()` function.

Comment: need more clarification about this issue `self.es.search() `